# Is there a way to search cells to find a partial match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to build a tool which will allow me to search for the value held in "B3" in a second sheet. After it finds that value in sheet2,through a loop, it will then copy and paste the cells next to it into sheet1 in a specified destination. My issue is after trying to use the instr function to pull this in I keep receiving an error. Is there somethign I'm missing in my instring or is there something else I should add?

Here's the code I've used so far:

```
 Dim InterfaceNumber As Integer

 Dim finalrow As Integer

 Dim i As Integer 'counter

 Dim InterfaceInformation As Variant

 InterfaceNumber = Sheets("Trackers Search").Range("B3").Value

  finalrow = Sheets("Trackers").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 4 To finalrow

   If instr("C3:D50"),InterfaceNumber) Then

 Sheets("trackers").Range("B" & i & ":E" & i).Copy

   InterfaceInformation = Sheets("trackers").Range("B" & i & ":E" & i).Copy

   Sheets("Trackers Search").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 
    0).PasteSpecial

Else


 End If
```

I expect to be able to loop through the "Trackers" sheet and find all the cells that match the value in cell "B3" and to paste it into The first sheet in range B8:E8

Comment: Yeah, you’re using it wrong, have you looked at the doco for InStr? Even if your approach did work, you’ve also got parentheses problems.

Comment: I’ll work with .find(what=InterfaceNumber) etc instead of InStr...

Comment: Thanks Irene! I'll try that and see. I'm new to VBA so any advice/tips are welcomed.

Comment: After you fix your InStr it should work. MS Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function